# When did we discover air?

Tags: science

I'm certain that ancient man knew of wind and of our need to breathe, but when did air as a distinct material become obvious? I notice that the four classical elements are water, *wind*, fire, and earth. As no other gasses were known until the chemists replaced the alchemists, when did air as a medium become known? Did Newton know of air?

Comment: air or oxygen, if oxygen [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Wilhelm_Scheele) guy discovered it.

Comment: The answer, my friend, is blowin' in the wind. 8-)}

Comment: Could you edit your question to clarify what you've looked into already, complete with links and references, and context if applicable? In particular, please let us know what you find missing or unclear about the [Wikipedia](https://www.acs.org/content/acs/en/education/whatischemistry/landmarks/josephpriestleyoxygen.html) entry on the topic. This allows those who might want to answer to do so without needing to redo the work you've already done. You might find it helpful to review the site tour and Help Centre and, in particular, How to Ask.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Philo of Byzantium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philo_of_Byzantium), wrote Pneumatica. Which included details of devices operated by air pressure. They knew about it far earlier than Newton. He seems to be an early source for knowing about the properties of air with respect to combustion, [link](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:BlF_54TgKUoJ:www.math.harvard.edu/~knill/pedagogy/waterexperiment/vera_rivera_nunez.pdf+&hl=en&gl=uk&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESjAzUrHud4QcJimjHpTAuceVODbt65l6uutVFPK6VM2ObXVMeLYT9iKNW38qW0GTPfQYcSaPp3Fu214U2ShQHhbs1Oolhd1412Fk05b3tIC7q2LXY4OOboFJSbBSTLzdcohfqfr&sig=AHIEtbSydWV8l7XySM5J_FlJ3aB_6EVMmQ).

But if we're talking about classical Greek elements, I thought Empedocles's [four elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empedocles#The_four_elements) included air. However it is "wind" in the [Babylonian idea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_element#Classical_elements_in_Babylonia) from the Enûma Eliš (18th-16th century BCE). I'm not sure what the difference between air and wind is unfortunately, and I don't have access to papers anymore. [This](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0039368102000225) is what I would read if I did.

Comment: I also liked the second page of this: https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:fLbv87C4eE0J:mattson.creighton.edu/GasWebDocuments/History_Gas_Chemistry.pdf+&hl=en&gl=uk&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESgZxnGEa1Oa0jFSzg0HS9bGmww0Gu_xZls6Lzj7INfQoaIjyyYDHo-5w2Rj6leQOK2_jP7mvBi59hK8YiS9sr0dX3vSztnKy-DE4eYkz53eVV3S97for2j1WmNFdO-vP1h6t1kX&sig=AHIEtbTL3G0VKYvMxLr2jA-Le4vQDu2ejw

Comment: Thank you. In fact, in English it is translated to 'air' but in Hebrew it is translated to 'wind'. If someone could read the original Byz then I would be interested in hearing their comments.

Comment: I found the Wikipedia link to [Air (Classical Element)[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_%28classical_element%29] from your Empedocles link. That is about as close to an answer as I expect to come, so I'm accepting this answer. Thank you!